# How can I replace in Excel multiple values in one cell with values in a column using a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have zero knowledge of VBA and I'm trying to create a macro that will replace "/1", "/2", etc. in cell C17 with the values in the column AF.

[image: Screenshot]

So far I have this, but it only replaces the first value (i.e. "/1") and stops there. Considering that I know close to nothing about VBA, I'm surprised that this even did anything. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!!

```
Sub questiontext()

Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Range("AJ3:AJ52")
    Set ReplaceRng = Range("AF3:AF52")

Range("C17").Replace What:=InputRng, Replacement:=ReplaceRng, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think I'm following what is happening here... C17 appears to be part of your labels with some boxes; I see `columns("AJ")` have those "/1" etc., and see that "columns("AF")` include your strings... can you more clearly state the desired situation?

Comment: I'll try. I have some text in C17 containing a series of questions labeled "/1" etc. that I want to replace with the strings in columns("AF"). I created columns("AJ") with all the question labels that appear in C17. In other words, I want to look for AJ3 in C17 and replace it with AF3, then move on to AJ4 and replace it in C17 with AF4 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to loop down a column and perform that line of code; you can use a loop to replace within a formula:

```
Dim i As Long:  For i = 3 to 52
    Range("C17").Formula = Replace( Range("C17").Formula, Range("AJ" & i).Value, Range("AF" & i).Value)
Next i
```

Depending on your intent, you may want to save your base formula for `C17` so you can reference and replace later, otherwise you'll keep modifying the same formula and possibly remove items, e.g., /1 and /17 each have "/1" and may have unintended consequences; looping in reverse would benefit this scenario, e.g.:

```
Dim i As Long:  For i = 52 to 3 Step -1
    Range("C17").Formula = Replace( Range("C17").Formula, Range("AJ" & i).Value, Range("AF" & i).Value)
Next i
```

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much!! I figured I'd have to use Loop, but I had no idea how. And thank you for the suggestion; I hadn't thought of that, but what you say makes a lot of sense.